# MySQL Error in Syntax near '@points

Tags: mysql

need your help,

this is the complete message of the error:

```
[SQL]: DB error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@points
```

now, this is my sql code

```
query_sql("UPDATE `cp_v4p_voters` SET `points` = (.@points - " + .@usedPoints + ") WHERE account_id = '" + .@account_id + "'");
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what's the reason behind using dot before @point?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be more like

```
<?php
    $query_sql=("UPDATE `cp_v4p_voters` SET `points` = (.@points - " +     .@usedPoints + ") WHERE account_id = '" + .@account_id + "'");
?>
```

but you seem to be using + and . and - not really sure what you are trying to achieve maybe give me sql dump of some rows from cp_v4p_voters and a bit more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your column `points` is a text column. So you need to use single quotes `''` around your value. for example instead of `col=(val)` you need `col=('val')`

```
query_sql("UPDATE `cp_v4p_voters` SET `points` = ('.@points - " + .@usedPoints + "') 
WHERE account_id = '" + .@account_id + "'");
```